# error generating Graph API token using Atlassian(confluence) plugin sdk in java

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am trying to generate the graph API token for azure AD using atlassian plugin module in java ,  I entered the dependencies in the POM file , built the jar , deploy it on confluence it is showing the error ,

> Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve
> com.atlassian.tutorial.myConfluenceMacro [306](R 306.0): missing
> requirement [com.atlassian.tutorial.myConfluenceMacro [306](R 306.0)]
> osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.microsoft.aad.adal4j)
> Unresolved requirements: [[com.atlassian.tutorial.myConfluenceMacro
> [306](R 306.0)] osgi.wiring.package;
> (osgi.wiring.package=com.microsoft.aad.adal4j)]
>     at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4398)
>     at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2308)
>     at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:1006)
>     at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:992)
>     at com.atlassian.plugin.osgi.factory.OsgiPlugin.enableInternal(OsgiPlugin.java:405)

I have used `<scope>provided</scope>` under the dependcies and built the jar but the jar is getting diabled when uploading in confluence manage app section.

below are the dependencies I have tried:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.oauth.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>atlassian-oauth-client-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.oauth.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>atlassian-oauth-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

the POM file is not allowing me to add these dependencies,
similar for the following:

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>com.atlassian.oauth</groupId> 
<artifactId>atlassian-oauth2</artifactId> 
<version>1.9.0</version> 
</dependency>


<dependency> 
<groupId>com.atlassian.oauth.client</groupId>
 <artifactId>atlassian-oauth-client-api</artifactId> 
<version>1.0.6</version> 
</dependency>

 <dependency>
 <groupId>com.atlassian.oauth.client</groupId>
 <artifactId>atlassian-oauth-client-core</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.6</version>
 </dependency>
```

is there any other way to resolve these error in dependencies or any other way to generate graph API token with sdk plugin code .